# Does Eclipse have a bean builder UI for JavaBeans components?

Tags: java, eclipse, javabeans

First of all I would like to create a JavaBean.
I created a simple class "Person" in eclipse, which respects the JavaBean standard requirements, such as:

- implements Serializable
- default constructor
- private fields
- public getter/setter methods

As far as I know there are some bean builder tools, such as Netbeans etc. 
But does eclipse have such a plugin? A bean builder plugin? 
My purpose would be to export my class as a bean, and to use it in another classes, only for the sake of exemplification and I would like to use Eclipse if it is possible. The problem is that I don't know how to declare/export my class as a java bean.

Comment: If you write the class, and its field then you can do `generate setters/getters` `generate construtor` etc

Comment: what do you mean by export . Are you new in java programming. You have to include the  class in class path and import in your class where you are using it

Comment: I don't want to export it as a simple class. I would like to use it as a bean, and referencing it in another classes. As I know the bean objects can be used without using the "new" keyword.

Comment: you mean you want to use Dependency injection

Comment: JavaBean doesn't in any way take away using `new`. It's a normal class.

Comment: Yes. Also thank you for the title clarification. It's more explicit now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a JavaBean is a class as any other java class (with specific characteristics of course, but still a java class). So, I think there is no special export notion for a JavaBean class, all you can do is look for the javabean.java class in your project folder and you can use it everywhere you want to. I suggest that you try to do what I said to you. I hope that my answer will help you :)

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this

Comment: How can i use it everywhere?

Comment: Here, everywhere = any java developing context (IDE, CMD, ..)